# MobileFirst install - cannot connect to database appcntr after it was created

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

Trying to install MobileFirst 6.3 (Using DB2 v 10.5, Windows Server 2012 R2 std) - and during the creation of the DB2 APPCNTR database stage, I get the error:

```
Creating database APPCNTR (this may take 5 minutes) ...failed:
Cannot connect to database 'APPCNTR' with user 'db2admin' after it was     created: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1035,     SQLSTATE=57019, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.17.29
```

This is a clean installation of DB2, with no other programs using it (that I know of). The db2admin user is a member of my windows security group 'DB2ADMS' as well as 'DB2USERS' just in case

If I go back in the installer, then press next again, it says the database is already created (not sure if it's fully successful or partial)....

Comment: Sounds like something is not good with the database setup: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01035n.html

Comment: @IdanAdar The link talks about open connections on the database - but it's the MobileFirst installer that's creating the database so, there can't be anything but our installer connecting to it, and there are no other databases available (clean install of DB2)

Comment: The error code matches at least. Also verify that you are using the correct DB2 driver version for the DB2 database version that you're using.

Comment: I'm selecting the driver from the DB2 installation folder during the MobileFirst setup: SQLLIB\java\db2jcc4.jar

Comment: I also get the same error when using driver SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar (with the error code changing at the end to DRIVER=3.67.27)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the database has been created successfully but for some reason, it is not possible to connect to the database via JDBC.

The explanation for the error message can be found here -- it can be many reasons: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01035n.html

When that happens to me the issue is often resolved by waiting a bit and retarting Installation Manager. Restarting the DB2 instance helps also. (If you don't restart Installation Manager, it believes it needs to create the database and fails because the database was created).

If the problem is not resolved by waiting a bit, you can also create the database manually prior running install Manager using that procedure (use a different database name than the one that is considered busy):
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_creating_the_db2_database_for_App_Center.html
Then use that database name when running Installation Manager,

Comment: If I restart the installation of MobileFirst server at this point, on the second occasion, it says the database already exists, so it does not configure it. This leaves us with an empty database to configure manually. 

Your link leads to a 404 page... but I think I know where you're sending me